# Where to report upstream bugs of kde-l10n-si?

Tags: bug-reporting, upstream

I'm trying to file an upstream bug for [`kde-l10n-si` bug 1460444](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-l10n-si/+bug/1460444). Yet, I didn't find any category at https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi which matches l10n packages and i18n which is something different imo doesn't contain an si component.

I reported the bug, so I don't want the "affects me too" function or provide information with `apport-collect`.

Comment: Close Voters: This is not offtopic, it's about how to do Ubuntu Bug Triage, reporting an ubuntu observed bug to the upstream, and likely should be under a different tag space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of `kde-l10n-si` says:

```
$ apt-cache show kde-l10n-si | grep http 
Homepage: http://l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=si
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
```

And [the homepage](http://l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=si) navigation area links to [the HowTo, whose section on bug reports](http://l10n.kde.org/docs/translation-howto/bug-reports.html) says:

> Translation bugs are in the "component" named "i18n", there is a
>   "product" named "general" and there are other "products" for many
>   language teams. (Your team can be added too, either as a private email
>   address or with a mailing list address. Ask the Sysadmins to get it if
>   you want it.) Mostly "component" and "product" are written together
>   e.g. i18n/general .

And the description for the `i18n/general` product is:

> all bugs not for other components

So, presuming the Sinhala team haven't had the sysadmins create a product for them, file your bug in `i18n/general`.